# How to add the current column reference in SUM function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Something like this:

```
=SUM($A1:CELL("ADDRESS"))
```

Is there any way to do this?

Edit:
[image: consumed stock control]

My request for help is just for ease of maintenance, I'm not an expert on this kind of thing, so please ignore my ignorance.

The columns marked in yellow are the inventory shipments, and every time they are consumed, conditional formatting makes them green.

Whenever I create new submissions, I need to edit the formula and add the current column reference (it's marked in yellow on the right: SUM($F5:$G5)).

I would like to be able to leave it the way I ordered it, to create an easy rule for anyone to add to the column.

Comment: @BigBen It's for conditional formatting

Comment: Just use a relative reference then, e.g. `SUM($A$1:A1)` and apply the rule starting in cell A1.

Comment: I'll edit the question for more context

Comment: @BigBen tell me if you understand now. thank you

Comment: IIUC, you should be able to use `SOMA($F5:G5)`

Comment: I would like to use the same function for all columns if possible.

Comment: Right. When you apply that formula to multiple cells, Excel updates the relative references. So G5 gets updated to H5, I5, etc. for cells to the right, and G6, G7, G8 for cells down the column.

Comment: Each column corresponds to a stock shipping date, I created a formula for each column. As you can see in the range on the right: G5:G9988 (column G corresponds to the 14th March date)

Is there any way to do this without being like this?

Comment: You should create one formula and apply it to multiple columns.

Comment: Here is the formula for that column: =IF(E(E5<>0;G5<>0);SUM($F5:$G5)<=IF(ISNUMBER(E5);E5)). How would it be applying a general to the entire range of F5:ZZZ5? Column E is named "Vendas"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a rule with mixed references:

```
=AND($E5<>0,F5<>0,ISNUMBER($E5),SUM($F5:F5)<=$E5)
```

and apply it to multiple columns:

[image]

In Portuguese (I think):

```
=E($E5<>0;F5<>0;E.NUM($E5);SOMA($F5:F5)<=$E5)
```

Comment: It took me a while to understand how conditional formatting formulas work, I even thought of this with a different resource to reapply to other cells. But I think I understand, the secret is where you lock with the "$". Thanks!